# How do I cast a VSTO Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument to an OpenXml WordprocessingDocument on the fly?

Tags: casting, ms-word, vsto, openxml, word-interop

I have an application program that provides the ability to export a document as an XML file. The exported document is in `OpenXml` format and is recognized/editable using Word (See Note 1 below). The document contains a rather convoluted table structure where the "top" table has a few cells each of which contain a child table. My task is to write a VSTO add-in that provides the user a button. When the user opens one of these XML files and clicks the button, the add-in locates and manipulates text within the "top" table and child tables.

My original code (see "Code" below) used the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table class to locate each cell within the "top" table and child tables.

Things got weird when my code started throwing an exception because on one of the tables, the Column.Count property showed 3, but accessing the cell using `objTable.Cell(row, column)` threw `The requested member of the collection does not exist`. Using the debugger, I can see that column 3 does not exist even thought the Count property shows 3 (Note: I observed that the Column indices are 1-based, not zero based).

Do I need to cast the Word document to an OpenXml document on the fly within the add-in and use the OpenXml Table class to successfully access the tables?

Thinking that this is the answer, I installed `Open XML Package Editor for Modern Visual Studios` and added references for `DocumentFormat.OpenXml` and `Windows.Base`. However, when I do the cast:

```
WordprocessingDocument doc = (WordprocessingDocument)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
```

It throws this exception:

> System.InvalidCastException. Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.DocumentClass' to class type
>   'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument'. Instances
>   of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do
>   not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces
>   as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls
>   for the IID of the interface.

**Can I/How do I cast Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument to an OpenXml WordprocessingDocument on the fly inside my VSTO add-in?**

**Code**

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngDoc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Content;

int i = 1;

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table objTable in rngDoc.Tables)
{
    DumpTable(objTable: objTable, tableNumber: i++, childTableNumber: 0);
}


private void DumpTable(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table objTable, int tableNumber, int childTableNumber)
{
    for (int row = 1; row <= objTable.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 1; column <= objTable.Columns.Count; column++)
        {
            Cell cell = null;

            try
            {
                cell = objTable.Cell(row, column);

                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Table {0}.{1}. row={2}. column={3}. cell text={4}", tableNumber, childTableNumber, row, column, cell.Range.Text));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Table {0}.{1}. row={2} + column={3} threw exception: {4}", tableNumber, childTableNumber, row, column, e.Message));
            }
        }
    }

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Table {0}.{1}. Start Child Tables", tableNumber, childTableNumber));

    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Table child_tb in objTable.Tables)
    {
        DumpTable(child_tb, tableNumber, childTableNumber + 1);
    }

    Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Table {0}.{1}. End Child Tables", tableNumber, childTableNumber++));
}
```

**Note 1**

I assume the document is is OpenXml format based on an examination of the file's preamble (see `xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<w:wordDocument xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" 
xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" 
xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" 
xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" 
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" 
xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2" 
xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core" 
xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/AllInOneOctoFBISchema.xsd" 
xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/AllInOneOctoFBIFirstFooterSchema.xsd" 
w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" 
w:ocxPresent="no" xml:space="preserve"><w:ignoreSubtree 
w:val="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml/sp2"/>
.
.
remainder of file
```

Comment: I think perhaps you've pointed out the fallacy of my assumption, i.e., this is not an `OpenXml` document, rather it's a `WordProcessingML` document. Based on Eugene's answer, I tried opening the xml file using the 'Open XML SDK 2.5 Productivity Tool' and it says the document is corrupted. This makes sense sense its not `OpenXml` :-). You wouldn't believe how convoluted the table structure is in this XML file. `I think your gut feeling is accurate`. I can get away with catching and ignoring the exceptions because I need to just locate and modify the text in some of the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct cast. These objects are not related to each other. You need to save the document and then open the saved file using the Open XML SDK. See [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

While Eugene is right in saying that you can't cast a

- `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document`

to a

- `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WordprocessingDocument`,

there is a way to convert between the two. This is shown in the following example:

```cs
// Get hold of a Range that you want to transform, using the Open XML SDK.
// In this example, document.Range() represents the whole document.
Document document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
Range range = document.Range();

// Create a WordprocessingDocument reflecting that Range from the Flat OPC
// string returned by the Range.WordOpenXML property.
WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.FromFlatOpcString(range.WordOpenXML);

// Transform the WordprocessingDocument.
// ...

// Convert the WordprocessingDocument back into a Flat OPC string and insert
// it into the original Range.
range.InsertXML(wordDocument.ToFlatOpcString());
```

Note that you don't get 100% of the full `WordprocessingDocument` this way. While it is clearly enough data to transform the contents of the main document part (incl. your tables), you need to:

1. save and close the document in Word;
2. open, transform, and close the `WordprocessingDocument`; and
3. reopen the document in Word

to perform a full transformation of styles, numbering, etc.